# Matching 2 sheets/dataset based on range

Tags: excel, powerbi

My sheet 1 looks like this,

[image]

My sheet 2 looks like this

[image]

I'm looking for the formula/method to merge these two sheets based on the "Start", "Stop" column from both the tables.

I have to merge the sheets based on the start/stop range of the sheet 2 comes between the start/stop range of the sheet 1.

Comment: Have a look on here for vlookup() and index() with match() - lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple without VBA or array formulas, I would create an extra column that combines "start" and "stop" and then use vlookup to find the right rows:

Add this formula to both tables in an extra column (A is easiest for the one to lookup in)  lets say that start and stop are in E and F

`=E1&"-"&F1"` Make sure to put something between the values to prevent duplicates.

And use `VLOOKUP` to add columns C and D to A and B by searching for the newly made start-stop value.